# When creating a CLI with npm, is there a lib to save the token

Tags: npm, command-line-interface

I am creating a CLI using nodejs, and all my API calls that the CLI will make require a auth token.
So when someone makes an API call, I will first need to authenticate and then save the session/auth token and use that for any subsequent API calls.

Is there a nodejs library that helps in this regard by chance?

Comment: Try Node.js package Passport

Answer (score 0):

Use Passport with JWT (JSON Web Tokens). Specifically Passport-JWT Stratagy.

Once a user is logged in, they are sent a token, on subsequent requests that token is then used to authenticate (if authentication is required).

Comment: does it save it to file?  because this is a cli and they might run commands after a few minutes apart etc.

Comment: Usually you pass the token you receive as part of any subsequent requests (you could still pass in the token via the CLI?). There might be a better strategy for your particular need, but not sure, have a search over at http://www.passportjs.org/